# Can Axis Client-Config.wsdd config be picked up from JBoss?

Tags: apache-axis, jboss5.x

I have a client for a 3rd party webservice that had to be created using the Azis WSDL2Java tool.  Every web request must be encrypted using an Encryption handler provided by the 3rd party and the incoming responses myst be Decrypted in the same format.  This all works really well, except that I have the handlers specified in a client-config.wsdd in the src/main/resources of my jar.  one of the parameters of the client-config is a username and one is the location to a key file. This will need to be deployed to many different environments where the user and key location will differ, and it's not going to be feasible to change the values each time then rebuild. Is there a way I can either pass in parameters to my wsdd or place the wsdd in the $JBOSS_HOME/server//conf folder etc? (I am using JBoss 5.1.0.GA)

The wsdd looks like this

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<deployment xmlns="http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/" xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/providers/java">
  <globalConfiguration>
    <requestFlow>
     <handler name="EncryptionHandler" type="java:com.3rdparty.services.util.EncryptionHandler" >
     <parameter name="userName" value="myuser"/>
     <parameter name="keyFile" value="/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/<name>/conf/my.key"/>
     <parameter name="passwordCallbackClass" value="com.3rdparty.security.client.PWCallback"/>
     </handler>
    </requestFlow>
    <responseFlow>
     <handler name="DecryptionHandler" type="java:com.3rdparty.services.util.DecryptionHandler" >
     <parameter name="userName" value="myuser"/>
     <parameter name="keyFile" value="/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/<name>/conf/my.key"/>
     </handler>
    </responseFlow>
     </globalConfiguration>
     <transport name="http" pivot="java:org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender"/>
<transport name="local" pivot="java:org.apache.axis.transport.local.LocalSender"/>
<transport name="java" pivot="java:org.apache.axis.transport.java.JavaSender"/>
</deployment>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the system property `axis.ClientConfigFile` to specify a particular directory of the `client-config.wsdd` file.